# swagger. Как создать документацию?

Tags: php, html, api, swagger

Есть ресурс [сваггер-едитор](http://editor.swagger.io/#/), хочу снерировать доку. Нажимаю Generate Client -> HTML, но документация приходит кривая. Без скриптов. 
Что необходимо сделать, чтобы сгенерировать нормальную доку?

Comment: пример хотьбы привели кусок кода я незнаю, по которому пытаетесь сгенерить доку.

Comment: там же есть свой пример. Хотя бы его сгенерировать.